# How to remove ubuntu on ubuntu and reinstall ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, reboot

I couldn t find a solution since maybe 5 hours. I have checked everything on Internet. Here is my problem,

I dual booted Ubuntu 14.02 beside windows 7. I removed windows 's files accidentally. I went on with ubuntu. Today It said there isn t enough disk space. So I tried everything to fix it.

Finally I want to delete everything and reinstall ubuntu. But nothing seems to work. Please help.

I have a bootable usb with iso file of ubuntu 14.02. Everytime I restart I just see 5 options, none of them is working.

Comment: Sounds like you're not booting from USB, but getting to the bootloader menu, that shows what's installed on the hard drive. If you want to install something, you need to boot, hit repeatedly boot selection key (it's different for each computer, for me it's F12 ), and then select USB

Comment: You were right, I couldn t reboot correctly! Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution I see would be to resize your ubuntu partition to fill the space left by windows. You could do so with a Gparted LiveCD/LiveUSB. It would consist in deleting the windows partitions first, then expanding your ubuntu partition.

If you want to proceed with a clean install, you will have to delete all your partitions with the ubuntu installer, and then perform a clean install.

Of course, the first step is to build a proper bootable medium. This seems to be your main problem here. You could use Unetbootin to do this. Its interface is quite user-friendly, you shouldn't have any problem with it.

When you have your bootable USB drive, restart your computer, and accede your BIOS to select it as the boot medium. Usually there is a boot menu, but depending on your computer, it can be triggered by pressing F2, F8, F12, Escape or delete during early startup.

Comment: I couldn t reboot correctly , thanks for help. I managed to reboot and reinstall a brand new ubuntu!